# Active Record has_many :through remove one associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

This may be a very basic oversight on my part, but I can't seem to recall a simple method for removing an association between two objects joined via `has_many :through`. IE:

```
class Photo
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Tags
  has_many :photos, :through => :taggings
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Taggings
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

If you have two objects, `tag` and `photo`, you can associate them just by doing this:

```
photo.tags << tag
```

So, is there an equally simple opposite to this? ie:

```
photo.tags.remove tag
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

here's what you want:

```
photo.tags.delete(tag)
```

Comment: Note that this will not trigger `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` callbacks on the join model - use `destroy` in place of `delete` if you require that.