# Rails 4: how does rails handle join tables in "has_many through" relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-many

I am new to rails. I'm trying to understand relationships in the database. I have 2 tables, users and disciplines and a join table called interests. Users have many disciplines through interests and disciplines have many users through interests.

But what if I want to update a users interests? Do I have to delete all entries directly in the join table and then create a new 'set' or is there a clever rails way that handles this where I can work directly on the outside models, users and disciplines.

I've looked for a direct answer to this for rails 4 without success.

Many thanks

Comment: you might look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/13217991/1657377

Comment: That looks good, but, using the example in that question, can you equally use....photo.tags.update(tag)?